# Find closest time range from current date

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have some list of objects. Each of them contains specific "from" and "to" time range specified.

So for example:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

data class MyObject(
val from: String?,
val to: String?
)
```

The `asUtcDateTime()` is just my extension method that converts the given String do DateTime

How can I find the nearest object which:

- is not in today time range
- will be closest from today (future or past)?

What I've tried so far is just to get the nearest MyObject from the past and future like so:

```
    val now = DateTime.now()

     val nearestPastSchedule = allSchedules
        .sortedBy { it.to.asUtcDateTime() }
        .filter { it.to.asUtcDateTime() != null }
        .lastOrNull { it.to.asUtcDateTime()!!.millis < now.withTimeAtStartOfDay().millis }

    val nearestFutureSchedule = allSchedules
        .sortedBy { it.from.asUtcDateTime() }
        .filter { it.from.asUtcDateTime() != null }
        .lastOrNull { it.from.asUtcDateTime()!!.millis > now.withTimeAtStartOfDay().millis }
```

Don't know what would be good solution in terms of comparing them (considered that there are nullable) and also have the actual MyObject returned for each of them

Comment: which package/dependency does `DateTime` belong to? what did you try so far?

Comment: What did you try so far? If you do this often, it might be useful to use a sorted list.

Comment: @Roland Check what I've tried so far

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Check what I've tried so far

Comment: lets rephrase the problem... you are looking for `MyObject` whose `to` or `from` is the nearest to now? but in the future? so... maybe (pseudo-code): `allSchedules.filter { it.after(now) }.sortedBy { min(abs(now - it.from), abs(now - it.to)) }.first()`? or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting, you can find the specified element yourself. I do so by finding the absolute minimum difference between now and the time specified in the object.

For simplicity reasons, I adjusted the data class to use ZonedDateTime (assuming Java >=8 to be available):

```
    data class MyObject(
            val from: ZonedDateTime?,
            val to: ZonedDateTime?
    )
```

With that, you can filter and find the minimum absolute value between now and the corresponding time:

```
val nearestPastSchedule = 
    allSchedules.filter { it.to != null }
                .minBy { abs(it.to!!.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - now) }
val nearestFutureSchedule =
    allSchedules.filter { it.from != null }
                .minBy { abs(it.from!!.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - now) }
```